# Trying to update Spring Cloud Dataflow v2.9.4 to 2.11.2 on Pivotal CloudFoundry but getting errors during deployment

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to update our instance of Spring Cloud DataFlow from 2.9.4 to 2.11.2 but I'm getting errors during deployment to our PCF (Pivotal CloudFoundry) environment. I am totally unsure about what to do so I was hoping someone here would have an idea.

I am deploying through a custom manifest as we have custom configuration requirements that as far as we are able to tell cannot be covered by using the SCDF from the PCF marketplace. Specifically this comes down to disabling streams, but in full the custom manifest is:

```yaml
applications:
  - name: scdf-server
    buildpacks:
     - java_buildpack_latest
    path: spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.11.2.jar
    routes:
      - route: https://our-scdf-route.some-pcf-host.com
    health-check-type: http
    health-check-http-endpoint: /management/health
    memory: 2G
    disk_quota: 2G
    instances: 1
    timeout: 180
    services:
      - postgres-database
      - config-service
    env:
      LANG: en_US.utf8
      LC_ALL: en_US.utf8
      SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME: scdf-server
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: cloud
      JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE: '{ jre: { version: 17.+ } }'
      JAVA_OPTS: '-Duser.timezone=Europe/Amsterdam'
      JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION: '{enabled: false}'
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_STREAMS_ENABLED: false
      SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_ENABLE_LOCAL_PLATFORM: false
      SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_DISCOVERY_ENABLED: false
      KUBERNETES_AUTH_TRYKUBECONFIG: false
      SPRING_AUTOCONFIGURE_EXCLUDE: org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.kubernetes.KubernetesAutoConfiguration
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE: 6
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_MINIMUM_IDLE: 1
      # Release connection after 10 seconds idle.
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_IDLE_TIMEOUT: 10000
      SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_CLIENT_SERVER_URI: https://our-scdf-skipper-server-route.some-pcf-host.com/api
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_SERVER_URI: https://our-scdf-route.some-pcf-host.com
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_URL: ((CF_API_URL))
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_DOMAIN: ((APP_DOMAIN))
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_ORG: ((CF_ORG))
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_SPACE: ((CF_SPACE))
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_USERNAME: ((CF_USER))
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_PASSWORD: ((CF_PASSWORD))
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_SKIP_SSL_VALIDATION: true
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_SCHEDULERURL: ((SCHEDULER_URL))
      # Set buildpacks to empty so that CloudFoundry let the buildpacks decide whether they can run the app
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_BUILDPACKS: ""
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_BUILDPACK: ""
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_SERVICES: postgres-database, config-service # other services...
      # Composed task runner requires at least 4 connections.
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_ENV[SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE]: 4
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_ENV[SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_MINIMUM_IDLE]: 0
      # Release connection after 10 seconds idle.
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_ENV[SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_IDLE_TIMEOUT]: 10000
      # Let the nodejs buildpack set the max_old_space_size for nodejs apps
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_ENV[OPTIMIZE_MEMORY]: true
      # Let the application know which space we are running on:
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_ENV[CF_SPACE]: ((CF_SPACE))
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_HEALTHCHECK: process
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_USESPRINGAPPLICATIONJSON: false
      SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ENABLE_RANDOM_APP_NAME_PREFIX: true
      SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_SCHEDULES_ENABLED: true
      # Suppress warning exception for k8s config
      LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_FABRIC8_CONFIG: INFO
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '
        {
           "maven" : {
              "localRepository": null,
               "remoteRepositories" : {
                  "springRepo" : {
                    "url" : "((NEXUS_URL))((NEXUS_INTERNAL_REPO))",
                    "auth": {
                      "username": "((NEXUS_USER))",
                      "password": "((NEXUS_PASSWORD))"
                    }
                  },
                  "repo2": {
                    "url": "((NEXUS_URL))((NEXUS_EXTERNAL_REPO))"
                  }
               }
           },
           "spring.cloud.dataflow" : {
                "task.platform.cloudfoundry.accounts" : {
                    "default" : {
                        "connection" : {
                            "url" : "((CF_API_URL))",
                            "domain" : "((APP_DOMAIN))",
                            "org" : "((CF_ORG))",
                            "space" : "((CF_SPACE))",
                            "username" : "((CF_USER))",
                            "password" : "((CF_PASSWORD))",
                            "skipSsValidation" : true
                        },
                        "deployment" : {
                          "services" : "postgres-database, config-service"
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
        }'
```

This largely follows the documentation: https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/cloudfoundry/cf-cli/#installing-using-a-manifest

The URL of the JAR we download for deployment is https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/2.11.2/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.11.2.jar

When deploying this manifest with the command:

```bash
cf push ${APP_NAME_NEW} \
  -f ${MANIFEST_FILE} \
  -p "${ARTIFACT_FILE}" \
  --no-start \
  --var COMMITREF="${COMMITREF}" \
  --var CF_SPACE="${CF_SPACE}" \
  --var CF_ORG="${cfOrg}" \
  --var CF_API_URL="${cfApi}" \
  --var APP_DOMAIN="${APP_DOMAIN}" \
  --var CF_USER="${cfUser}" \
  --var CF_PASSWORD="${cfPass}" \
  --var NEXUS_USER="${NEXUS_USER}" \
  --var NEXUS_PASSWORD="${NEXUS_PASSWORD}" \
  --var NEXUS_URL="${NEXUS_URL}" \
  --var NEXUS_INTERNAL_REPO="${NEXUS_INTERNAL_REPO}" \
  --var NEXUS_EXTERNAL_REPO="${NEXUS_EXTERNAL_REPO}" \
  --var SCHEDULER_URL="${SCHEDULER_URL}"
```

Between push and start our script only uses `cf set-env` to set the HTTP proxy.

Now as for the error I get, this is the logging of when starting the application on our PCF. I have dumped this on gist because otherwise this post exceeds the maximum body length: https://gist.github.com/favna/05f42f8ab1e55f3548f599fa2d0df558

As can be seen here I get some error about an unresolved namespace seemingly related to K8s, despite the fact that above the Spring banner it explicitly logs that it detects not running in K8s and disabling its profile activation.

So far I have tried:

- Adjusting the manifest to match the documentation more closely, this is when I added the `"spring.cloud.dataflow"` section at the bottom, however this didn't change the error (although I suspect it was a necessary change regardless?)
- Ensuring the skipper server is actually up and running before deployment. We don't actually use the skipper server and it's been disabled for a long time now so I figured this wouldn't be necessary.

I would expect deployment of the new SCDF version to work smoothly so we can start testing it and eventually using it.

The primary reason for wanting to update is that when updating our applications to Spring Boot 3.2.0 (from 3.1.5) as well as updating the matching `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies` from `2022.0.4` to `2023.0.0` that currently I get the error in SCDF 2.9.4:

```
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: io/pivotal/cfenv/core/CfEnv has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Seeing as this is clearly related to Java vesions I figured I'd upgrade SCDF and add the config lines for using Java 17 (`JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE: '{ jre: { version: 17.+ } }'` and `BP_JVM_VERSION: -jdk17`) and then go from there.

Comment: Try adding env `KUBERNETES_AUTH_TRYKUBECONFIG=false`

Comment: Or rather `SPRING_AUTOCONFIGURE_EXCLUDE=org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.kubernetes.KubernetesAutoConfiguration`

Comment: @CorneilduPlessis, alas again. I added both but to no avail. I also noticed that I hadn't yet set `JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE` to explicitly use Java 17 when analyzing the logs further so I also added the env var. I have updated the logs I get with all these recent changes. I changed the embedded logs to a Gist link due to exceeding maximum body length.

Comment: SCDF 2.11.x on CF runs with Java 8 and only passes the Java 17 version when deploying Spring Boot 3.x workloads.

Comment: Hm alright well I reverted that change but it ultimately didn't matter in regards to the Kubernetes error.

Answer (score -1):

SCDF prior to 2.10 will not correctly launch application built using Spring Boot 3

SCDF 2.11.x will provide the correct arguments when launching tasks or streams registered as boot3 apps.
I suggest removing:

```
BP_JVM_VERSION: -jdk17
JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE: '{ jre: { version: 17.+ } }'
```

from your manifest.

Comment: I have made this change but it hasn't actually addressed the core problem of deployment failing as shown in the logs under the line "Now as for the error I get, this is the logging of when starting the application on our PCF"

Comment: Try adding the following to your configuration `spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.enabled=false` or environment `SPRING_CLOUD_KUBERNETES_DISCOVERY_ENABLED=false`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll be sure to try it. That said, I'm currently on vacation for a few weeks so I'll report back when I have tried it in a couple of weeks from now.

Comment: Hi @corneil-du-plessis, I finally got around looking into your suggestion. I added the line right below and similar to my line `SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_ENABLE_LOCAL_PLATFORM: false` and tried another deployment, but sadly I get the exact same error. I updated the original post with the new property in the manifest file so there is a full view of what the file looks like now.